# MySQL server failing in install on Amazon Linux machine due to missing systemd

Tags: mysql, systemd, redmine, amazon-linux

I'm currently trying to install Redmine on a machine running the latest Amazon Linux.

One of the first steps I'm told to do is to install MySQL server using the command `sudo yum install mysql-server`.

However when I run this I am getting the following error output:

```
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.7.18-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: systemd
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I try installing systemd:

```
sudo yum install systemd
```

But no dice:

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
7 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
No package systemd available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I see online that Amazon Linux doesn't use/support systemd. But I can't find an answer anywhere telling me how to install MySQL server.

This is all the information about the machine itself:

```
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2017.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2017.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2017.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2017.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
Amazon Linux AMI release 2017.03
```

Is anyone able to help with this?

Comment: Don't use Amazon Linux. It's a broken, half-maintained RHEL derivative. Just use CentOS - you'll have a much better time.

Comment: I see. OK, I'll give that a go.